# UtteranceProgressListener is not called in a service doing both STT and TTS

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a need to perform STT and TTS in the same app. The STT is working as expected. The TTS part is working to the extent that the text is read out correctly. But, the microphone picks up the text read by the TTS, and performs STT again.

So, we have a loop and the TTS repeats the voice again and again, even though the user has spoken it once.

To avoid this issue, I tried to perform muting / unmuting of mic, from UtteranceProgressListener. This whole functionality is defined in a service.

I have the following code in "`onCreate()`" method of the service.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
    VoiceRecognitionListener.getInstance().setListener(this); // Here we set the current listener

    // TTS initialization
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    UtteranceProgressListener upListener = new UtteranceProgressListener()
    {
        public void enableMic(String s)
        {
            if(s.contains(UTTERANCE_ID)) {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                // Unmute the microphone
                Toast.makeText(context, "Unmuting the mic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);
            }
            return;
        }

        public void disableMic(String s)
        {
            if(s.equals(UTTERANCE_ID)) {
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                // Unmute the microphone
                Toast.makeText(context, "Muting the mic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
            }
            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(String s) {
            disableMic(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String s) {
            enableMic(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop(String s, boolean i) {
            enableMic(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s) {
            enableMic(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s, int e) {
            enableMic(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginSynthesis(String s, int sampleRateInHz, int audioFormat, int channelCount)
        {
            disableMic(s);
        }
    };
    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(upListener);
}
```

The following method calls the TTS speak method.

```
    public int speakOut(String text, String utteranceId)
{
    int rc = 0; // Return code
    try
    {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utteranceId);
        rc = tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params, utteranceId);
    }
    catch(RuntimeException r) {
        Toast.makeText(context, r.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Please help with your suggestions. I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: You can try moving `tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(upListener);` into the TTS engine's `OnInit()` callback method, which is called when the TTS engine is ready. I'm not sure if it's necessary. At least the UtteranceProgressListener needs to be set before calling `speak()`, but that should already happen as it's in `onCreate()´.

Comment: Thanks Markus. I will try this.